# 500 , error, Internal Server Error ajax to laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a call to a laravel controller with this route:

```
Route::post('obtenerNodos', 'panelController@obtenerNodos');
```

but I just get : `500 , error, Internal Server Error`

```
$.ajax({        
    url: "obtenerNodos",
    data: { id: '1' },
    method: 'post',
    success: function () {
         console.log("done");
         //do something
    },error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         console.log(xhr.status+" ,"+" "+ajaxOptions+", "+thrownError);
    }

});
```

this is the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Client; use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class panelController extends Controller {
    public function viewpanel(){
        return view('admin.panel');
    }

    public function viewstats(){
        return view('admin.estadisticas');
    }

    public function viewfacs(){
        $client = new Client();        
        $res = $client->get('http://smartbill.co:332/SmartBill2/rest/factura/get?codigo=FA001100x01&token=fd25834e78c7c4f806e9e56b307d16c18a847197');
        $respuesta = json_decode( $res->getBody()->getContents(),true);
        return view('admin.factura_add')->with('facturas', $respuesta);
    }

    public function viewfacsreg(){
        return view('admin.factura_reg');
    }

    public function cerrarSesion(){
        //matar sesion antes de hacer la redirreccion
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function obtenerNodos($id){
        $id = Input::get("id");
        return "done";
    }
}
```

And this is the full error:

> POST http://binario.com/obtenerNodos 500 (Internal Server Error) send
>   @ jquery.min.js:6 ajax @ jquery.min.js:6 (anonymous) @ viewfacsreg:199

Comment: can you share `obtenerNodos()` code from your controller ?

Comment: also can you share the stack trace error

Comment: @yoeunes already edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep your route like this :

```
Route::post('obtenerNodos', 'panelController@obtenerNodos');
```

change your `obtenerNodos()` function to  this :

```
public function obtenerNodos(Request $request){

    $id = $request->id;

    return "done";
}
```

and don't forget to import this at the top : `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Add this JavaScript that sets defaults for all ajax request in jQuery. Preferably in a js file that is included across your app:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
})
```

make sure you have a meta tag like this in your blade page :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Already made that you said, but now i get this error:

POST http://binario.com/obtenerNodos 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ viewfacsreg:199

Comment: http://i943.photobucket.com/albums/ad274/Carlos_Jaramillo_Corrales/Sin%20ttulo_zpsncl3hake.png

Comment: @CarlosJaramilloCorrales look at my updated answer, now it should work

Comment: @younes thank you a lot for your help, it works just perfect now.

Comment: you're welcome @CarlosJaramilloCorrales can you upvote the answer please

Comment: @youeunes it says that i don't have more than 15 rep to do it,

Comment: @CarlosJaramilloCorrales yes you're right, thank you anyway ^^